# Pass a file to container using docker exec_run python docker client

Tags: python, docker

I am using [docker sdk for python](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html). How do I pass a file to container using `exec_run` function.

I want to replicate the following docker exec command:

`docker exec -i -u postgres <Insert the id find above> pg_restore -C -d postgres < filename`

Above command loads a postgres backup. `filename` is the name of the file and resides on host machine from which exec command is being run.

I am trying this:

```
containers[0].exec_run("/bin/bash -c 'pg_restore -C -d postgres <'" + filename, stdout=True, stderr=True, user='postgres')
print(exec_log[1])
```

Here the file resides inside another docker container in which a python application is running which uses python docker client.

I am getting this:
`b'/bin/bash: 2019-04-29-postgres_db.dump: No such file or directory\n'`

I have looked into `put_archive` but that would require extracting the file inside the container. Is there a way of doing this using `exec_run` or any other simpler way?

Thanks

Comment: You don’t need Docker for this (and correspondingly root-level access to both the database and the host).  Install the PostgreSQL tooling on the host and run `pg_restore` directly from there.

Comment: In my use-case I cant do that.

Answer (score 0):

As a work around, you can mount a volume in your docker image that contain that file. Then you can use it from there.

```
container = context.client.containers.run(
    image="ipostgres",
    auto_remove=True,
    detach=True,
    volumes={"/host/machine/store: {'bind': '/opt/whatever', 'mode': 'ro'}, },
)
```

Then

```
exec_run("/bin/bash -c 'pg_restore -C -d postgres < /opt/whatever/filename'", stdout=True, stderr=True, user='postgres')
```